# Получить все данные с базы данных по запросу с сайта

Tags: php, mysql

Всем привет!
У меня есть в базе данных две таблицы log_ban и log_ucp в этих таблицах идет запись User | Данные | Данные | Данные
Как мне сделать форму куда я буду вводить имя юзера, и какой нужен скрипт чтобы он отправлял запрос в бд и получал все строки с таблицы с таким именем и показывал на страницу через echo?

Comment: так сложно погуглить примеры работы с бд?

Comment: Не нашел нужного примера.

Comment: @Илья, http://g.zeos.in/?q=%D0%B2%D1%8B%D0%B2%D0%BE%D0%B4%20%D0%B8%D0%B7%20%D0%B1%D0%B0%D0%B7%D1%8B%20%D0%B4%D0%B0%D0%BD%D0%BD%D1%8B%D1%85%20php